# SignalR client connect to different server

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, angular, signalr

I'm using SignalR version 2.x in my ASP.Net MVC application and has same version of signalr in my angular client app.
Asp.net MVC application hosted in `http://localhost:42080` and angular app hosted in `http://localhost:4200`.
I've installed `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` and enabled cors in mvc application.

```
[HubName("msg")]
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string user, string message)
    {
        Clients.User(user).Send(user, message);
    }
}
```

I want to connect to signalr server from my angular app but can't.

```
const connection = $.hubConnection(this.config.AdminUrl); // http://localhost:42080
const chat = connection.createHubProxy('msg'); // chat.server or chat.client are undefined
```

I also tried:

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:42080/signalr';
var hub = $.connection.msg; // hub = undefined
$.connection.hub.start() // this will result Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>
```

how can I connect to signalr server hosted in different server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to config your Startup.cs like this

```cs
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration 
                {
                    // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                    // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                    // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                    // EnableJSONP = true
                };
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
```

Note

> Don't set jQuery.support.cors to true in your code.
>
> Don't set jQuery.support.cors to true
>
> SignalR handles the use of CORS. Setting jQuery.support.cors to true
>   disables JSONP because it causes SignalR to assume the browser
>   supports CORS.

if you are connecting to a different server, specify the URL before calling the start method, as shown in the following example:

JavaScript

```
$.connection.hub.url = '<yourbackendurl>;
```

Note

> Normally you register event handlers before calling the start method
>   to establish the connection.

Detail can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-establish-a-cross-domain-connection)

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested in your answer but unfortunately problem still exists.

Comment: Make sure you can load the signalr script. Is there any error in your console ?

Comment: I saved `http://backend.com/signalr/hubs` and imported it in my angular app and everything seems to working now.

Comment: If my answer work for you please vote up. Thank you @mhesabi